# indexOf and BufferedReader not working for me

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader, indexof

I am trying to get the index of the element on the arraylist with the use of BufferedReader. It processes perfectly and no errors but when every time I gave input element, it gives an output of -1. Any element, it's always -1. What is wrong?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

class family {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String input;

ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

al.add("Mama");
al.add("Papa");
al.add("Sister");
al.add("baby");


System.out.println(al);

System.out.println("Family Member Number: ");
input = br.readLine();

System.out.println(al.indexOf("input"));

}

}
```

What I want to happen is that the output must be equal to their index. Like Mama = 0, Papa = 1 and so on...

Answer (score 4):

Try `indexOf(input)`, without the quotes. What you've written only makes sense if the array is expected to contain the `string` `"input"`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you do supply the requested string correctly at the prompt (including the correct case), you should call

```
a1.indexOf(input);
```

i.e., without the quotes. Otherwise, you always try to find the index of the string "input", which of course is -1, since you have no such string in the `ArrayList`;